# Rotate animation and translate?

Tags: css

The rotate animation won't work with translate. I get, that I have to put translate in the same property with the rotate, but how is this possible when using keyframes? Code is like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);    

    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  
    }
}

@keyframes rotating {
    from{
        transform: rotate(0deg);    
    }
    to{
        transform: rotate(360deg);  
    }
}

img{
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite; 
    animation: rotating 2s linear infinite; 
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

This will make the rotation, but it disables the translate. If I put the translate into the rotating animation, the translate is being animated as well(ofcourse).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The 2022+ answer

You can work around this by using individual property transforms which have [pretty good browser support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scale).

In short, use the properties like `scale`, `translate`, etc. instead of `transform`.

Side note: You don't need browser-specific properties for anything related to transforms or animations these days.

---

### The original 2014 answer

The issue is that the `transform` in the animation is overriding the default `transform:translate`. In this case, you can combine them in the animation itself but it has to be hard coded.

```
@keyframes rotating {
    from {
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(0deg);    
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(360deg);  
    }
}
```

If you need it to be dynamic, you can nest it in an element and animate one while not affecting the other - most likely translate the parent and rotate the child.

If you absolutely *cannot* have more than one element, you can affect the transform matrix for the element using JavaScript, in which case using an animation library like GSAP would be advantageous.